# How can I measure switching power losses in a MOSFET accurately?

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement, hall-effect

I am going to measure under scope the switching power losses in the MOSFETs of my micro power inverter. In any case, the handling load current doesn't exceed 1 A at 24/48 Vrms.

Firstly, I've thought to introduce shunt resistors (I have some with 100 Ω, 25 W) but found that there exist other facilities out there, especially Hall-effect current sensor ICs like the Allegro [ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.ashx) and the TI [TMCS1100A4](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmcs1100.pdf).

These ICs have an 80 kHz bandwidth and introduce some phase shift which would delay the sensed current and falsify the power-loss calculation.

In your opinion, what do you suggest?

PS. Current clamps are out of my budget at least for now.

Comment: 100 ohms at 1 A would drop 100 V. You'd want something more like 100 milliohm to 1 ohm.

Comment: @Transistor Yes I know. Those power resistors are primarily bought to serve as load and won't be appropriate to sense the current through the MOSFET

Comment: OK, but if they're your load then the current through the resistors will be the same as the current through the MOSFETs. Measure the voltage across the resistors, divide by 100 and that's your current. Watch out where you attach your ground clips though and don't create a short-circuit through your scope's ground.

Comment: Not exactly the same because the multilevel power inverter structure is composed with several MOSFETs and hence the load current curve at switching would not be the same as that flowing through individual power switch.

Comment: As you mentioned if you use a current sensor or probe you may have significant delay between your voltage and current measurements.  If your scope can't adjust for the delay between channels (some have that capability) you may have to export the data from the scope and time shift the waveforms manually, assuming the scope can save the data to a USB drive or dump it over GPIB or USB.

Comment: @ John D, good point for mentioning the adjustment in time delay. This function is fortunately available in my Picoscope.